# Is there an api to monitor Microsoft Edge browser version and its release dates?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there an api to monitor Microsoft Edge browser version and its release dates?
more like https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/all.json
for google chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for endpoint for finding current released version of Microsoft edge, you can get information from following,

[Edge Latest Stable Version](https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_STABLE)

For more information you can find answer on following
[Microsoft Edge Latest Version Number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71644819)