# Is there a link to get the latest Microsoft Edge version number?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm looking for a link to get the latest driver version number for Microsoft Edge similar to Google Chrome's link: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE

I have a function to return a string of the version number. Then, I can create a download link like so:

```
private String getLatestChromeDriverVersion(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
    }

String chromeDownloadUrl = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + getLatestChromeDriverVersion() + "/chromedriver_win32.zip";
```

I've been searching around for something similar for Edge, but I can't find anything. They have this page for downloading the driver: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ but nothing like /latest or /stable.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that MS release numbers different versions based on the different platforms, ie the latest version for Android may not share the same version number as the latest for Windows, see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge for an example

Answer (score 3):

You can get the latest version number that has been given in the official documentation via these two links:

```
https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_STABLE
```

and

```
https://msedgewebdriverstorage.blob.core.windows.net/edgewebdriver/LATEST_STABLE
```

**Note**: They all return a file instead of directly returning a version number like chrome, you need to get the version number from this file.

A simple demo:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
   .uri(URI.create("https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/LATEST_STABLE"))
   .build();
        
HttpResponse<String> response  = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        
String version = response.body().replaceAll("[^\\d|.]", "");
System.out.println(version);
```

Comment: I'm noticing that I get different versions from those two links.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest Edge versions as a JSON. It has the latest versions by channel (Product), for each platform and arch.

Consumer Builds: ( Windows, MacOS, Linux, Android, IOS )

```
https://edgeupdates.microsoft.com/api/products
```

Enterprise Builds: ( Windows, MacOS, Linux, GPO Policy Files )

```
https://edgeupdates.microsoft.com/api/products?view=enterprise
```

The builds are split into channels ( Stable, Beta, Dev, Canary )

Example:

```
{
        "Product": "Dev",
        "Releases": [
            {
                "ReleaseId": 43248,
                "Platform": "MacOS",
                "Architecture": "universal",
                "CVEs": [],
                "ProductVersion": "110.0.1587.2",
                "Artifacts": [
                    {
                        "ArtifactName": "pkg",
                        "Location": "https://officecdnmac.microsoft.com/pr/03adf619-38c6-4249-95ff-4a01c0ffc962/MacAutoupdate/MicrosoftEdgeDev-110.0.1587.2.pkg",
                        "Hash": "046BB1322257530A66BCCEC6E821F2548163BEC1818C85B6FEB1E986DB62EBC0",
                        "HashAlgorithm": "SHA256",
                        "SizeInBytes": 352551023
                    },
                    {
                        "ArtifactName": "plist",
                        "Location": "https://officecdnmac.microsoft.com/pr/03adf619-38c6-4249-95ff-4a01c0ffc962/MacAutoupdate/MicrosoftEdgeDev-110.0.1587.2.plist",
                        "Hash": "4C8EB411D4A93FB721FF7A90031C95D696E97BB2D9051C48501C0BEB12AFBB19",
                        "HashAlgorithm": "SHA256",
                        "SizeInBytes": 3053
                    }
                ],
                "PublishedTime": "2023-01-05T19:43:00",
                "ExpectedExpiryDate": "2023-04-05T19:43:00"
            },
            {
                "ReleaseId": 43170,
                "Platform": "Windows",
                "Architecture": "x64",
                "CVEs": [],
                "ProductVersion": "110.0.1587.1",
                "Artifacts": [
                    {
                        "ArtifactName": "msi",
                        "Location": "https://msedge.sf.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/4de84b50-b3a8-4751-afb8-73812bce8713/MicrosoftEdgeDevEnterpriseX64.msi",
                        "Hash": "4DC76967D9BA3BFDB275B8D40AE3A9ED7F77C661879BFC1CD6C4264EBDC09540",
                        "HashAlgorithm": "SHA256",
                        "SizeInBytes": 147148800
                    }
                ],
                "PublishedTime": "2023-01-04T20:22:00",
                "ExpectedExpiryDate": "2023-04-04T20:22:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xudong Peng answer is correct.
I would just add that you can get the latest version for a certain MAJOR version via this link:

```
https://msedgewebdriverstorage.blob.core.windows.net/edgewebdriver/LATEST_RELEASE_<MAJOR_VERSION>
```

Once again, it will return a file that you will need to parse to obtain the latest version.

This is usefull if like in my case your Edge browser is not in the latest version and you want to retrieve the latest edgedriver for this version.